# Unable to capture error message - selenium java junit

Tags: java, html, text, selenium, message

I need to capture the error messages displayed, i tried many methods but every method throws exception --unable to find element,
pls help with the code. These are the methods i tried.Also, there is no ID, it is div element. something like this...

```
<div id="webformErrors" class="text" name="errorContent">
<div>
There were 4 errors:
<ul>
<li>
You did not enter a value for:
<b>First Name</b>
</li>
<li>
You did not enter a value for:
<b>Last Name</b>
</li>
<li>
<li>

//String errormsg;
![enter image description here][1]errormsg = Hcd.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id=webformErrors']/text()")).getText();

// WebElement divElement = Hcd.findElement(By.className("errorContent"));

// Hcd.findElement(By.name("There were 4 errors:")).isDisplayed();

**String pstring = Hcd.findElement(By.id("webformErrors")).getText();
        System.out.println(pstring);
```

Comment: This question requires proof-reading. Please review it and fix up the formatting and structure.

Answer (score 0):

You have given the classname and name wrong. classname is "text" and name is "errorContent".

```
WebElement divElement = Hcd.findElement(By.className("text"));
```